# How to choose shared memory id (shmop/SimpleSHM)

Tags: php, shared-memory

I want to use shared memory with PHP, like describe [here (SimpleSHM)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-shared-memory/). But I wonder how to choose the `$systemid` correctly. I have to "hardcode" the number (`864, 897` in the examples) in my PHP code so different processes can interact.

But how do I make sure the same id is not used elsewhere (other application, conflicts)? If I generate the id dynamically at runtime I have a chicken / egg problem (how to share the id among my PHP segments using the shared memory).

Ok, I could generate the memory in one place, write the id to a file and read it in other places also using the shared memory. But is this the best way to go?

Code examples:

```
<?php
$systemid = 864; // System ID for the shared memory segment
$mode = "c"; // Access mode
$permissions = 0755; // Permissions for the shared memory segment
$size = 1024; // Size, in bytes, of the segment
$shmid = shmop_open($systemid, $mode, $permissions, $size);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$new = new SimpleSHM(897);
$new->write('Sample');
echo $new->read();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical method of generating a unique key for a SHM segment is to use the [`ftok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftok.php) function:

```
$key = ftok(__FILE__, "0");
```

This will generate a value that is (probably*) unique to the file the call appears in. If you need another key in the same file, use a different character for the second argument. (It must be a single character.)

*: There are actually some rare situations where `ftok()` will return the same value for multiple files. This is unavoidable, as the maximum value of the key is smaller than the maximum number of files that can exist on a filesystem. If this becomes an issue, you will likely need to use some other method of sharing data.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to have multiple different PHP scripts/libraries/classes all share memory for different purposes, necessitating a number of different $systemid values, I'd strongly suggest creating a constant for each one to give it a name. Define these constants in a file by themselves and then include/require that file in any PHP script that intends to make use of the shared memory.

E.g.:

```
<?php
define("MY_SHARED_MEMORY_PURPOSE_X", 864);
define("MY_SHARED_MEMORY_PURPOSE_Y", 897);
```

Etc.

If you want to avoid include/require statements and are using an autoloader, you can attach these constants to a class:

```
class My_Shared_Memory_Constants {
    class PURPOSE_X = 864;
    class PURPOSE_Y = 897;
}
```

then you can refer to them like so:

```
$new = new SimpleSHm(My_Shared_Memory_Constants::PURPOSE_X);
```

If you are concerned about conflicts with other libraries or software beyond your control, you can use the **n** flag when creating shared memory segments. If one already exists for the same segment, it should fail. If this is your concern, you should maintain the systemids you are able to successfully open in an associative array (or in a db table which can be shared between processes) so that your code can refer to them by name.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make sure no other PHP program (not under my control) is also using the same id (like `864`). To me  it looks like I have to check if the id is already used, and if to use another one. But then I have to share the id as well. All examples I have found use some kind of magic number, but I have no idea where the number comes from (why `864`, not `123` or `666`)?

Comment: If you are concerned about conflicts with other libraries, you would need to dynamically manage your shared memory ids. Whenever you try to create one, use the **n** flag -- if one already exists with the same ID, it will fail. At least I think that's how it works. The docs are worded a bit strangely: http://php.net/shmop_open

Comment: And I would need to share the dynamically generated id - I use shared memory because I need to share data between processes. The only way to share the id (I have found) is to write it in a file. And I wonder if this is the only way to solve the issue.

Comment: @HorstWalter Oh my! I see your conundrum. If you have two distinct processes, they have to have some shared key table so they know which ids correspond to which shared blocks. Writing a file or defining a database table where they can share this info seems like the only way. Of course it'll be inefficient when setting things up, but once a process retrieves the correct ID from the shared table for some KEY_NAME, then you should be OK. I haven't given it a lot of thought, but it seems to me that file or db will be required.